# Reason of Non-singleton dimensions mismatch in data under PCA

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, machine-learning, pca

During pca analysis using built in pca function in matlab, I faced the following error. Data is actually a feature vector obtained from 30 MR images.

```
>> size(data)
  ans =
  30   281   389   104 

[coeff score varience] = pca(data);

Error using bsxfun
Non-singleton dimensions of the two input arrays must match each other.

Error in pca>localSVD (line 468)
x = bsxfun(@times, x, PhiSqrt);

Error in pca (line 341)
    [U,sigma, coeff, wasNaN] = localSVD(x, n,...
```

Would you let me know any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](http://de.mathworks.com/help/stats/princomp.html) says it expects its input as an input matrix of `NxP`. You probably need to reshape your matrix to match this input requirements.

Comment: Do you know any function in matlab which can do pca  on 4d data. Or how to reshape so that performance of pca does not alter.@sietschie

Comment: I have no idea of MR images or what the purpose of PCA is in that context. What exactly is it you want to achieve?

Comment: how can i use built in PCA() function of matlab on my 4D data array. I have not idea about reshaping to be useful for pca()

Comment: Here is an [example](http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/167938-how-pca-can-be-applied-to-an-image-to-reduce-its-dimensionality-with-example) how to use it to perform PCA on an RGB-Image (basically 3D data because of the color channels). But if and how reshaping is helpful to you probably depends on the goal you have.

Comment: My goal is to obtain pca score, variance and coefficient of data to  reduce dimension of feature vector (data),

Comment: That is a very general statement. For example do you want to achieve something like the [eigenfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenface)?

Comment: I want to make shape of an object, may be its same as eigenfaces